# Call PHP function inside JavaScript inside echo

Tags: javascript, php

I have read the other similar questions, but not found the answer, so here it is:

```
<?php     
function load($page) {     
    echo "page: ".$page;
}

echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var page = 0;
  window.addEventListener(...., function(){
    var x = .....
    ......
    if(x = ....)
    {
      page = page + 1;
      var runQuery = '<?php load(page); ?>'
    }
  })
</script>  
";    
?>
```

The problem is that `<?php load(page); ?>` is not executed. If I write `load(page);` outside the echo, it works. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Oh my... That's a mess right there...

Comment: You cannot add php code inside javascript, only inside html tags

Comment: how can this be solved ?

Comment: You should solve this using [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: do you have an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the function to `return`:

```
function load($page) { 

    return "page: ".$page;
}
```

You're executing PHP with the `echo` so just use the return of `load()`:

```
echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            var page = 0;
            window.addEventListener(...., function(){
                var x = .....
                ......
                if(x = ....)
                {
                    page = page + 1;
                    var runQuery = '" . load($page) . "'
                }
            })
            </script>  
";
```

Comment: thank for the fast reply but still does not work. Every time window.addEventListener() is called, i would like to pass the value page to the load function.